# Aligning 3 buttons in div horizontally

Tags: html, css, button, xhtml, blogger

How can I align this 3 buttons horizontally in xhtml? This is for blogger by the way.

Here's my xhtml for the buttons:

```
<div class='fb-like'>
<fb:like action='like' expr:href='data:post.url' font='arial' layout='button_count' send='true' show_faces='true' width='450'/>
</div>

<div><b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<g:plusone annotation='inline' width='450' expr:href='data:post.url'></g:plusone>
</b:if></div>

<div><b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<a class='twitter-share-button' data-count='none' data-via='MarvinVista' expr:data-text='&quot;Currently reading: &quot; + data:post.title' expr:data-url='data:post.url' href='http://twitter.com/share'>Tweet</a>
</b:if></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place them in a containing `div`, give each `div` a set width and then `float` them to the left.

Comment: Can you post the complete code here? I tried doing that but it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class='fb-like share-button'>
<fb:like action='like' expr:href='data:post.url' font='arial' layout='button_count' send='true' show_faces='true' width='450'/>
</div>

<div class="share-button"><b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<g:plusone annotation='inline' width='450' expr:href='data:post.url'></g:plusone>
</b:if></div>

<div class="share-button"><b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<a class='twitter-share-button' data-count='none' data-via='MarvinVista' expr:data-text='&quot;Currently reading: &quot; + data:post.title' expr:data-url='data:post.url' href='http://twitter.com/share'>Tweet</a>
</b:if></div>
```

CSS

```
.share-button{display:inline-block;}
```